# Active Directory Password Authentication with Toad for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, toad

Is it possible to authenticate using Active Directory Password Authentication in Toad for SQL Server 6.8?

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio there's an option for this, but in Toad for SQL Server there's only "Windows Authentication" and "SQL Server Authentication".

My Login name is my email address, e.g., last.first@domain.com.
When I log in with SQL Server Authentication in Toad, it fails with the error message

> "Cannot open server "domain.com" requested by the login.  The login
>   failed."

Comment: Windows Authentication is (usually) Active Directory

Comment: In this case the database is hosted by a third party.  Toad only allows SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: Are you using the credentials for the SQL Server account that were given to you by the hosting company or your DBA? It's probably *not* the same credentials you use for other things tied to your account with the host.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Authentication uses the credentials that you are currently logged in with to authenticate.

The SQL server will need to use Windows Authentication and your AD user name will need to be given access.

Comment: The database is hosted by a third party.  When I enter the Server Name (which isn't the same domain), Authentication is disabled in Toad and SQL Server Authentication is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I was told in the Toad World forums that Toad for SQL Server 6.8 doesn't support Active Directory Password Authentication.